# file open throws an error float type

Tags: python, typeerror, file-handling

I have one method which takes many argument and also return multiple value

I am trying to open a file in that method but it shows me error like

```
fc=open("ABC.txt","a")
Type Error: 'float' object is not callable`
```

I don't know why it is showing this error i mean there is nothing like a float value.
The same line if I put in the calling function then it will create/open file successfully.

```
  fc=open("ABC.txt","a")
```

Comment: Have you some where defined a variable named `open`, which holds a floating value maybe ? `open = 5.5` ?

Comment: provide the full traceback and sample of the code

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be that somewhere else in your code, you have defined a variable called `open` which is storing a `float` type value. Example -

```
open = 0.1
```

The above line actually overwrites the inbuilt function `open` with the float variable, hence after this line any call to `open` would be referencing the float variable, causing the issue. You should not use built-in names for variables, try renaming the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must have used the variable name "open" and assigned a float to it in your code before arriving to this line of code.
Something like this:

```
open = 2.3
```

Note that it is considered very bad practice to use names of built-in functions for your own variables (you end up with issues like the one you are raising).

If you want to convince yourself that this is the issue, you can print your variable before your line:

```
print open
```

If you wanted to be very lazy, and can't find where "open" is in your code, you can use this horrible hack:

```
openTemp = open
del open
open("file_name", "a")
open = openTemp
```

This would be the fastest hack to get this to work, but I can't recommend it... Cleaning your code is better! I just mention it because it's interesting to see this, it is an example of how del works. In this case, it gives you back access to the built-in function.